# Random forest sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I am confused if explicit cross validation is necessary for Random Forest? In random forest we have Out of Bag samples and this can be used for computing test accuracy. Is explicit cross validation necessary. Is there any benefit of explicitly using CV in Random forest? I find it confusing to understand how CV in  Random forest  works based on this code
Here is my code:

```py
model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=cart, n_estimators=num_trees, random_state=seed)

results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold)

print(results.mean())
```

Comment: Are you asking about whether the classifier implicitly uses the out-of-bag samples for scoring? If that's the question, the answer is No, not by default. But, you can change the default behavior by changing `oob_score : bool, optional (default=False)` to `True`

Answer (score 3):

For each row in the dataset, the `OOB_score` is calculated using only a subset of the trees in the random forest. So it is not truly reflective of how the full random forest model would perform on any particular data row. So the short answer is: **you still need an explicit validation set** because the score of the model calculated on that set (be it R2, mean squared error etc.) is on predictions made by the *full* model.

I'll illustrate with an (over-simplified) example:

Suppose we're doing regression for predicting house sale prices. You have a dataset of **5 rows** (each row would contain the features of a particular house like its `YearBuilt`, `LivingArea`, `NumberOfGarages` for example), and a random forest with **3 trees**.

```
Tree 1     Tree 2     Tree 3
------     ------     ------
  1                      1
  2           2       
              3          3
  4                      
              5          5
```

where the numbers 1-5 denote the dataset row number used for training the tree (selected by bootstrapping). Then for example, rows 3 and 5 are not used in training Tree 1, and so forth.
Everything up to here is done regardless of whether you set `OOB_score` true or not in sklearn's RandomForest.

### OOB

If `OOB_score` is set to true: we go through each row in the dataset, and do the following.

- Row 1: only Tree 2 did not use it for fitting/training. Hence, we predict and get the score for row 1 using *only* Tree 2.
- Row 2: only Tree 3 did not use it for training. Hence, we predict and get the score for row 2 using *only* Tree 3.
- ...
- Row 4: Trees 2 and 3 did not use it for training. The predicted sale price for this house will be the average of the predictions by Tree 2 and Tree 3, but *not* Tree 1.

The `OOB_score` is just the average of the scores of the predictions across all the rows.

### Validation set

Compare this behaviour to if you had used an explicit validation set.
You would have (for example) 5 new rows in your validation dataset, and for each row you would pass it through **ALL** 3 trees in the forest, get their individual predictions and report the average as the final prediction of the sale price for that row.

Then you could report the mean squared error (or any other metric) on the entire validation set by taking the averages of the errors across all the rows.

### Summary

To summarize,

- in calculating the `OOB_score`, each row is only predicted on a **subset** of trees in the forest.
- Whereas the score reported on an explicit validation set is as a result of predicting each row with **all trees** in your forest, which is more representative of what actually happens in the test set. And so, this option is the one you want.
- On average, you would expect the `OOB_score` to be slightly worse than if you did on an explicit validation set because you use less trees to predict in the former.

#### Comment

That said, the two scores (OOB vs validation) are often quite close in practice.
If you have a small dataset and can't afford a validation set, OOB offers a good alternative.

But if your dataset is large enough, I would recommend setting aside an explicit validation set (or do cross-validation) anyway. In this case, the `OOB_score` is just an additional metric for which to judge your model by, but you should place a higher priority on the validation score. Work on improving this score.

---

### A second reason

There is also another case in which an explicit validation set is more suitable than using OOB: when there is a time-series involved.

An example is the Kaggle competition called [Corporación Favorita Grocery Sales Forecasting](https://www.kaggle.com/c/favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting), where your goal is to predict grocery prices per item per store over the **next 2 weeks** based on given data from the **past 4 years**.

In this case, your model (when it is done) will predict **future prices** in the test set.
Hence, you want to simulate this as far as possible when validating your model.
What this means is:

**You want construct the validation set to be as recent as possible (using data from the previous 2 weeks, for example).** Then, your training dataset is from 4 years ago till 2 weeks before 'today'. And you validate on the "future" validation set, from 2 weeks ago till 'today'.

You cannot do this if you use `OOB_score`: it generates the pseudo-validation set on random (consequence of bootstrapping), so the score you get from OOB will be less meaningful since you are not simulating the "future" effect described above.
Generating an explicit validation set would allow you the freedom for selecting the most recent data you have for validation, instead of random.

Answer (score 1):

oob_score is calculated when you do bootstrap sampling of your dataset while training the random forest model. This is a hyper parameter that one can control. Do note that OOB refers to the portion of the dataset which bootstrap algorithm. however the difference in the underlying manner in which bootstrapping itself work which leads to redudancies in records being consider in the train sample and out of sample as opposed to the train/test split that k-fold cross validation would do

Do note that one place where OOB can be particularly useful over cross validation is when using Random Forest or any bagging classifier for that matter on a large dataset when cross validation might turn computationally more consuming

Answer (score 0):

oob_score is not enough because:

1. it is calculated on some rows from the train set, which does not show your predictive power
2. I do not see any cv/stratification inside oob_score calculation (so if you have unbalanced dataset and oob_score rows are taken completely at random - it is bad)
3. it uses accuracy_score for classification and r2 for regression which may be not your desired metrics

Comment: About point 2, sklearn has a "weight" parameter when training the RF, which you can set to "balanced" or "balanced_subsample" in order to cope for unbalanced datasets.

Comment: For the rest, there are a few papers in the literature comparing OOB and CV. See for instance "Estimating Generalization Error on Two-Class
Datasets Using Out-of-Bag Estimates", Machine Learning, 48, 287–297, 2002

Comment: Thanks. About point 2: I know about 'balanced' option. I'm not sure that OOB uses it. Quickly reviewed the sklearn code though.

Comment: If you want to know what's in the sklearn RF code, I recommend having a look at Gilles Louppe's PhD, he's the one who implemented it and details are plenty in his PhD ! https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7502

Answer (score 0):

OOB error is an **unbiased estimate** of the prediction error from the Random forest. So reporting OOB error is sufficient. However,there is no harm in performing cross validation. Ideally both should be very close.

Answer (score 0):

#**What is Cross Validation?**#

Cross Validation is a technique which involves reserving a particular sample of a dataset on which you do not train the model. Later, you test your model on this sample before finalizing it.

```
Here are the steps involved in cross validation:

 1. You reserve a sample data set
 2. Train the model using the remaining part of the dataset Use
 3.the reserve sample of the test (validation) set. This will help you in gauging 
   the effectiveness of your model’s performance. If your model delivers a  
   result on validation data, go ahead with the current model. It rocks!
```

Answer (score 0):

"I am confused if explicit cross validation is necessary for Random Forest?"

Answer: no cross validation is not required for random forest to work.  However, cross validation will prove whether your model can generalize well.  It is good practice to include cross validation performance indicators as part of the pipeline then use the parameters of the cv.  The downside is cross validation takes resource and time to complete and for small datasets the payoff may not be signficant.